# All complex solutions to $e^x = y$

Tags: complex-numbers

I’m trying to solve the following equation: $e^x = 2$. The solution, which I already know, is: $i(2 \pi n - i\ln(2))$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The result makes perfect sense, however, I can’t seem to derive it from $re^{i\theta} = r(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))$.

If anyone has an idea on how to get to the result I’d greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you written $2$ in polar form? And note that if $x=a+bi$, then $e^x = e^a e^{ib}$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Solved! I forgot to try the 2 in polar form, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing what you are looking for.

$y=e^x=e^{u+iv}$, where $u$ and $v$ are real. $r=e^u$ and $\theta=v+2n\pi$.